# Equivalent metrics in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a very elementary question I can't resolve: Is it true, that if I'm asked to prove a statement about $R^n$, it's enough to prove it for any one induced metric since they're equivalent to each other?

Example: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658142/prove-that-mathbbrk-is-separable) was proven by pulling $|\cdot|_2$ out of thin air. Why? It doesn't hold for discrete metric. Am I really allowed to choose my metric of choice?

Comment: all Lp metrics are equivalent in the standard topology of Euclidean space. So when you proving statement only related to the topology properties, you can just pick one. For example, it’s the same when you pick the neighborhood as a box or as a ball.

Comment: @LouisPan: exactly, so how do I prove a statement about $R^n$ if it isn't specified which metric I'm supposed to use?

Comment: But if you using it in a problem like optimizing a function, that mostly is not only related to the topology properties, of course L1 and L2 norms are different

Comment: @LouisPan: thank you, that's what I thought.

Comment: @averagemathenjoyer: you are welcome. I combine the comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although related, "[norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics))" and "[metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))" are two very different notions. What one has is that

> all "norms" are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

But not all "metrics" on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent. For instance, the discrete metric and the Euclidean metric generate very different topologies on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

What metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to use should be clear under context. If it is not mentioned, it is very likely that one uses the [Euclidean metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance); but the precise one should be clear under context.

For the particular statement, you linked, one usually says:

> For every $n$, the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space is separable.

where the standard Euclidean distance is assumed.